# A question on continuous linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations

This is an exercise from Conway's Functional Analysis.

Let $X,Y$ be compact spaces and let $\tau:Y\to X$ be a continuous function. I have shown that the function $A:C(X)\to C(Y)$ defined by $Af(y)=f(\tau(y))$ for all $f\in C(X)$ and $y\in Y$ is a continuous linear operator and that $\|A\|=1$. Now I have to find necessary sufficient conditions such that $A$ is injective.

Suppose $\tau(Y)$ is dense in $X$. Let $x\in X$. Then there exists a sequence $(\tau(y_n))$ in $\tau(Y)$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\tau(y_n)=x$. Let $Af=0$. Then $f(\tau(y_n))=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and since $f$ is continuous, therefore $f(x)=0$. Hence $f=0$ and so $A$ is injective. Thus This condition is a sufficient one. Is it necessary? I have a little doubt. Please suggest something. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are dealing with compact Hausdorff spaces. If not, then not
all of this will work.

In this case $\tau(Y)$ is a compact, so closed subset of $X$ and then
$\tau(Y)$ is dense in $X$ iff $\tau(Y)=X$.

If $\tau(Y)\ne X$, take $x_0\in X-\tau(Y)$. By Tietze's extension theorem,
there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ with $f|_{\tau(Y)}=0$ and $f(x_0)=1$.
This $f$ is annihilated by the operator $A$.

Comment: My thoughts precisely!